# Regularity of a language contains more 1's than 0's

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

The language of all bitstrings with more 1s than 0s, i.e.,

$ A = \{x: 2\Sigma_{i}^{|x|} x_{i} > |x|\}$ is regular.

I know I should apply Pumping Lemma and the proof as well, what I cannot understand is' the meaning of question itself. To be more precise, my question is' how the formal and informal sections of the question are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the characters of the string as integers and add them up. The number you get is the number of ones in the string. If that number is more than half the length of the string, then there are more ones than zeros.

In my opinion, that's not a good way to specify the language. It's clever and correct but, honestly, if somebody has to ask a Stack Exchange question about the way you chose to write "More ones than zeros", then you made it way too hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

the notation $ L = \{w: 2*\Sigma_{i}^{|w|} w_{i} > |w|\} $

is the same as: $ L = \{w: 2*\Sigma_{w_i=1} w_{i} > |w|\} $

it means all the words $w$ s.t the number of $1$'s they contain is essentially greater than half of $|w|$ (the length of the word).

so if $x_0, x_1$ denote the number of $0$'s and $1$'s respectively, it is required that $2x_1 > |w|$

in other words, more than half the bits are $1$, so essentially the word has more $1's$ than $0$'s